# How to get specific data out of homepage (jsoup), for later if clause (Java, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup, element

I have a Homepage were we want to track if the location is empty/free. The Website is provided from an external Source as Service from them.

I already did the login on the Homepage via application and when I check the whole Document doc, it shows everything and what i want to have is also included.

Right now i have tried to specify the data I want to have (UID and Status) but i dont know how to do it.

I have no idea what to choose in the,

```
Elements data = doc.select("a");
```

I have tried using div.tiles and div.tableauDeBoard but didn't work.

Following is the Expected Output:

2652 free
2653 free
and so on

I hope i did everything right, its my first time posting here.

```
String URL = "..." //URL in there to shorten code
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements data = doc.select("a");
System.out.println(data.outerHTML());
<div id="tableauDeBoard" class="porlet-body" style="min-height:    40px;">
<div class="tiles">
    <a href="..."
    class="tile-v2 undefined popovers" data-content="Status :  free<hr>time : 4h22<hr>last change : 05.11.2019 at 18:46<hr>UID : 2652<hr> Typ : P<hr>connection OK" data-html="true" data-placement="auto" data-container="body" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="" title="">
    <div class="tile-code-ville"></div>
    <div class="tile-id-automate">2652</div>
    <div class="tile-infos"><span class="tile-icon-transmission">
    <img src="....png">
    </span><span class="tile-icon-jauge"></span></div></a>
    Same code 7 time with different UID/Time/Status
</div>
```

Comment: I finally found a weird solution for my problem.
So i took the Document doc and put it into a String and after that i made a Scanner method to go line by line and check if in the lines contains 3 keys words. With that it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way,

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TestJsoup{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.append("<div id=\"tableauDeBoard\" class=\"porlet-body\" style=\"min-height:    40px;\">");
        html.append(" <div class=\"tiles\">");
        html.append(" <a href=\"...\"");
        html.append(
                "class=\"tile-v2 undefined popovers\" data-content=\"Status :  free<hr>time : 4h22<hr>last change : 05.11.2019 at 18:46<hr>UID : 2652<hr> Typ : P<hr>connection OK\" data-html=\"true\" data-placement=\"auto\" data-container=\"body\" data-trigger=\"hover\" data-original-title=\"\" title=\"\">\r\n"
                        + "");
        html.append("<div class=\"tile-code-ville\"></div>");
        html.append("<div class=\"tile-id-automate\">2652</div>\r\n");
        html.append(" <div class=\"tile-infos\"><span class=\"tile-icon-transmission\">");
        html.append("<img src=\"....png\">\r\n");
        html.append("</span><span class=\"tile-icon-jauge\"></span></div></a>\r\n");
        html.append("document.write(<style type='text/css'>div,iframe { top: 0; position:absolute; }</style>');");
        html.append("</div>");
        html.append("</head><body></body> </html>");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html.toString());

        Elements allClassElements = doc.getElementsByClass("tiles"); //fetching the elements of the class "tiles"
        for (Element ele : allClassElements) {
            Elements links = ele.getElementsByTag("a"); // Finding the anchor tag which contains the required data
            for (Element link : links) { 
                String str = link.attr("data-content"); // to get the status value

                //Without Regex
                String oo = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1, str.indexOf("<hr>"));
                System.out.println(link.text() + " " + oo.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));  //link.text contains id value

                // Using Regex
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\:.*?\\<");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
                if (m.find())
                    System.out.println(link.text() + " "
                            + m.group().subSequence(1, m.group().length() - 1).toString().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
2652 free
2652 free
```

For more details around fetching the data using Jsoup, try visiting jsoup cookbook at
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Comment: I tried it with your method but it shows no results in the end.

Comment: I have modified the code to display the required value